# Why should a salt have the same length as the hashed value?

Tags: java, security, passwords

I've have read that a salt that is going to be used should have the same length as the hashed password, what is the reasoning behind this? Will it increase password protection?
I have read it 
[Here](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm):

> To make it impossible for an attacker to create a lookup table for every possible salt, the salt must be long. A good rule of thumb is to use a salt that is the same size as the output of the hash function. For example, the output of SHA256 is 256 bits (32 bytes), so the salt should be at least 32 random bytes.

Comment: where did you read this?

Comment: `To make it impossible for an attacker to create a lookup table for every possible salt, the salt must be long.` This is the answer

Comment: That's it? I am looking for more detailed explanation, I felt like that information is insufficient.

Comment: Your question is best suited for [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jweyrich: Or [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen or that :)

Comment: I didn't know that there's such thing as Security.SE, if so kindly move the question

Comment: That doesn't look like very authoritative source, more like some guys musings.  If you want to know more about this subject start from here http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Cryptography-Protocols-Algorithms-Edition/dp/0471117099/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1356704134&sr=8-1&keywords=applied+cryptography

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) is a good description of why password salts are needed.

No, you don't need your salt to be the same length as the password. In fact, none of the implementations listed in the article do that. Generally for each added bit of salt you're requiring an attacker to double his storage budget.

So having a 10 byte salt should be sufficient for today's level of technology.  Also note that the salt is binary value whereas passwords are not, so the salt length should be measured in bits/bytes and not characters.

Answer (score 4):

There's no particular need for the salt to be that long, although it certainly won't hurt.

The only real requirement a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) should satisfy is that it should be globally unique.  Even that isn't a *hard* requirement, in the sense that having a few duplicate salts doesn't really help an attacker much.  It's only if you get a *lot* of duplicates that the salt starts to lose its effectiveness.

In particular, due to the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), if salts are chosen randomly they should ideally be at least 2·log<sub>2</sub>(*n*) bits long, where *n* is the maximum number of users you expect to have (or, more generally, the maximum number of users you expect to use your chosen hashing method).  Of course, it's always a good idea to have some security margin on top of that.

In particular, the total population of the Earth is a bit over 2<sup>32</sup>.  This means that, even if every single person on the planet registered an account for your system, a 64-bit salt would still be quite sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The strength of the salt I suppose should be about the same as the strength of the password, because both should be resistant to brute force attacks.

A simple salt would be more vulnerable, but even a simple salt makes attacks vastly more laborious than having no salt.

Comment: A salt does not need to resist brute force attacks. It is not secret. All it needs to be is unique.